# What is 400080: Bad Request in Python while using Tableau Server Client

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-python-client

I'm exporting workbook to my local drive through tableau server by using tableau Server Client in python. I'm able to export some workbook but there are some Tableau Workbook which I'm enable to export there comes and error such as 400080: Bad Request

import os
import tableauserverclient as TSC

```
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('****', '*****', site_id="")
server = TSC.Server('https://****.net')
server.use_server_version()

tag_to_filter ='Summary'
new_folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Tableau\\TSC'

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    req_option = TSC.RequestOptions().page_size(300)
    all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get(req_option)
    print([workbook.name for workbook in all_workbooks])

    req_option.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name, TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.Equals, tag_to_filter))

    for workbook in TSC.Pager(server.workbooks, req_option):
        workbook_path = new_folder_path + workbook.name
        os.makedirs(workbook_path)

        server.workbooks.populate_views(workbook)
        for view in workbook.views:

            size = TSC.PDFRequestOptions.PageType.Tabloid
            orientation = TSC.PDFRequestOptions.Orientation.Landscape
            req_option = TSC.PDFRequestOptions(size, orientation)
            server.views.populate_pdf(view, req_option)

            file_path = workbook_path + '/' + view.name + '.pdf'
            print(view.name)
            print(file_path)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as image_file:
                image_file.write(view.pdf)


                print('\tPDF of {0} from {1} workbook'.format(view.name, workbook_path))
```

raise ServerResponseError.from_response(server_response.content, self.parent_srv.namespace)
tableauserverclient.server.endpoint.exceptions.ServerResponseError:

400080: Bad Request
There was a problem querying the pdf for view 'e91a2103-3347-4c91-8d51-a1ef88321492'.

Comment: "There was a problem querying the pdf"

Comment: Can you help me with how can the issue be resolved.

Comment: There were some connection request which were missing. By adding it the issue got resolve.